# The pullback commutes with the derivative. Proof for 1 forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

It's my first time learning differential forms and for that I am using Advanced Calculus from C.H. Edwards. Indeed, here are the definitions so far:

$\omega = Pdx + Qdy$ is a 1-form, $d\omega = (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dxdy$ is a 2-form. And, if $F:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ is a one to one function whose Jacobian is positive at every point, then define the pullback of $\omega$ and $\alpha$, where $\alpha = g(x,y)dxdy$ is a 2-form, as follows $$F^* \omega = P(F)(\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}dv) + Q(F)(\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}dv)$$ and $$F^*\alpha = (g\circ F)(det\ Jacobian(F))dudv.$$

So, using the above definitions, I need to prove that $F^* d\omega = dF^*\omega$. Indeed, after doing some computations, I got that
$$dF^*\omega = (\frac{\partial P\circ F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial Q\circ F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial P\circ F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u} - \frac{\partial Q\circ F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u})dudv = (\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u} + 
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u})dudv = (\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u} + 
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u})dudv= (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y})(\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u})dudv,$$
but I'm stuck, since
$$F^*d\omega = ((\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y})\circ F)(\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u})dudv$$
and from there I don't know how to get the expression I got in $dF^*\omega$.

Comment: You lost track of your differentials $du$ and $dv$. If you reinsert them you'll see some terms cancel off. Also, $P$ and $Q$ are functions of $x,y$, not $u,v$.

Comment: But P(F) and Q(F) are functions of $u,v$, no?

Comment: You still need to write out the chain rule for $d(P\circ F)$ and $d(Q\circ F)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin In which part? In $F^*d\omega$?

Comment: No, in $d(F^*\omega)$. Please do not write $P(F)$, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin After some computation I got that $dF^*\omega = (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y})(\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial })dudv$ using the chain rule. But how do I get the composition of F?

Comment: It’s there if you write the chain rule correctly :)

Comment: I still don't find the error. I edited my question adding the additional steps I did. What was my mistake? @TedShifrin

Comment: This is the problem with sloppy notation. When you write $\frac d{du}(P\circ F) = \frac{dP}{dx}\frac{dF}{du}$, where is $\frac{dP}{dx}$ evaluated?

Comment: At the domain of P? I'm not sure if I'm following you